# Word to describe crime, violence and criminal intent

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or shorter phrase that would describe: crime, (general) violence and criminal intent.

Essentially, anytime anyone is committing a crime or doing violence *or about to* commit crime/violence (malicious intent).

One context it would be used in would be "*The prevalence of X in local counties...*". For instance, if the word was `fizzbuzz`, then the use would "*The prevalence of fizzbuzz in local counties...*", as opposed to "*The prevalence of crime, violence and criminal intent in local counties...*" (which is a mouthful!). Thanks in advance! I can produce more usages if needed.

Comment: Why can't you just use the word 'crime'?

Comment: Agree simply "crime" seems like a reasonable fit here. Violence is very often accompanied by an element of crime (whether the violent act is itself a crime, or in response to a crime as in self-defense), and I don't see how you can even measure the prevalence of being "about to commit a crime" if that planning itself is not a crime as in conspiracy cases. Seems like odd hair-splitting to refer to non-criminal violence and non-criminal criminal intent, since both of those seem rather rare.

Comment: There’s no word I can think of. Intent is separate from the act itself.

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "criminal intent." Do you mean intent to commit a crime that may not yet be acted on and that in and of itself is not a crime or do you mean intent that is itself a crime, like how intent to commit a terrorist act, as one example, is itself a crime and how one can be arrested in advance of carrying out that intent and be charged with that crime?

Comment: *[Criminality](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criminality)* is an alternative to *crime* if you want to sound posher, but doesn't really add anything over *crime* here.

Comment: Unless you're going so far as "wrong thinking" nothing can describe both crime and criminal intent… that's why so many jurisdictions distinguish between murder/robbery/what and attempted  murder/robbery/what

"Violence" seems to cloud the issue. How is violent defence criminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two words, but I think "criminal activity" would be a good fit for your intended use.